# How is .classpath file in eclipse generated?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've a java project in the eclipse which has a .classpath file as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java"/>
<classpathentry excluding="**/*.java" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources"/>
<classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/generated/java"/>
<classpathentry excluding="**/*.java" kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
.......
<classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
```

How does this file gets generated? Can I edit this file?

I want a certificate file to be added to the project in path **target/test-classes**. Where do I configure that? 
My understanding is the **target/test-classes** folder gets generated after the ***mvn clean install***. So I think there should be some place where I can configure what all I need in the target folder. Do I need to configure it in **pom.xml** ?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve by editing those configurations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .classpath file reflects the content of all the settings that you apply manually to your BUILD PATH setup within your project.

In other words: while using the eclipse UI to setup the BUILD PATH, all that information goes into the .classpath file.

And it is perfectly possible to stop eclipse and make changes to that file within your preferred editor; then restart eclipse, probably do a full refresh; and (unless you messed up) the changes should be visible when opening your BUILD PATH settings again.

Comment: should it be committed to github repository? if a project is set to be used by multiple dev.

Comment: @CodeWorld Sure. When you have a project that is supposed to be used with multiple developers, and they are ALL using the same IDE, and you ONLY want to build your project using that IDE, then it makes sense to add (the necessary/important) config files (such as eclipse .classpath and .project ??? ) files to your git repository. The only exception would be: when you are starting a new, larger project, then you rather use gradle or maven or something, and use that as project description.